# android java syntax error in If statement

Tags: java, android

My apk is giving me two errors, down from 26 earlier this morning, but I dont seem to grasp the solution.  First question is there a good way/trick for keeping track of open and close parens and open and closed brackets?  Second question Is there something fundamentally wrong with my code?  The first error is at private Button btnExecute;  I think I am missing a closed bracket some where but dont know where..  When this worked last night I did not have a closed bracket near that line
The second error is closed bracket two lines up from end onClick.  I have a feeling it is missing a semicolon, paren or bracket.
The goal is read the value displayed in a spinner and use if statements to determine which routine to run.  Inside each routine I will check certain EditText for nulls or blanks and if not blank then a particular formula based on the spinner entry.

```
package com.androidbook.triviaquiz8;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.SpinnerAdapter;

public class QuizHelpActivity extends QuizActivity {

private EditText m1_sqs1;
private EditText m1_rs1;
private EditText m1_rs2;
private EditText m1_cd;
private EditText m1_els1;
private EditText m1_els2;

private EditText m1_sqs1_eng;
private EditText m1_rs1_eng;
private EditText m1_rs2_eng;
private EditText m1_cd_eng;
private EditText m1_els1_eng;
private EditText m1_els2_eng;

private EditText m1_sqs1_met;
private EditText m1_rs1_met;
private EditText m1_rs2_met;
private EditText m1_cd_met;
private EditText m1_els1_met;
private EditText m1_els2_met;

private EditText m1_sa_in;
private EditText m1_sa_ft;
private EditText m1_sa_mm;
private EditText m1_sa_m;

private EditText m1_ed_in;
private EditText m1_ed_ft;
private EditText m1_ed_mm;
private EditText m1_ed_m;

private Spinner m1_ss_spinner;
private Spinner m1_sqs1_spinner;
private Spinner m1_rs1_spinner;
private Spinner m1_rs2_spinner;
private Spinner m1_cd_spinner;
private Spinner m1_els1_spinner;
private Spinner m1_els2_spinner;

private QuizHelpActivity mContext;

private Button btnSave;
private Button btnClear;
private Button btnExecute;


// 
// onCreate - let the fun begin!
// 

@Override 
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){      
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
        mContext = this; 
        setContentView(R.layout.help);

        m1_sqs1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.m1_sqs1);
        m1_rs1  = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.m1_rs1);
        m1_rs2  = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.m1_rs2);
        m1_cd   = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.m1_cd);
        m1_els1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.m1_els1);
        m1_els2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.m1_els2);

        m1_sqs1_eng = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.m1_sqs1);
        m1_rs1_eng  = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.m1_rs1);
        m1_rs2_eng  = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.m1_rs2);
        m1_cd_eng   = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.m1_cd);
        m1_els1_eng = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.m1_els1);
        m1_els2_eng = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.m1_els2);

        m1_sqs1_met = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.m1_sqs1);
        m1_rs1_met  = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.m1_rs1);
        m1_rs2_met  = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.m1_rs2);
        m1_cd_met   = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.m1_cd);
        m1_els1_met = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.m1_els1);
        m1_els2_met = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.m1_els2);

        m1_sa_in    = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.m1_sa_in);
        m1_sa_ft    = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.m1_sa_ft);
        m1_sa_mm    = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.m1_sa_mm);
        m1_sa_m     = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.m1_sa_m);

        m1_ed_in    = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.m1_ed_in);
        m1_ed_ft    = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.m1_ed_ft);
        m1_ed_mm    = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.m1_ed_mm);
        m1_ed_m     = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.m1_ed_m);


        //
        // Create an OnClick Event in each button.
        //

        Button btnExecute   = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnExecute);
        Button btnSave      = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSave);
        Button btnClear     = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnClear);

        btnSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                }
            });
        btnClear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                }
            });
        btnExecute.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            private AlertDialog show;
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                AdapterView<SpinnerAdapter> m1ssspinner;
                if (((m1ssspinner.getSelectedItem() == "Square"))) {
                            if ((m1_sqs1.getText().length() == 0)           
                            || (m1_sqs1.getText().toString() == " "))   {           
                                show = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext).setTitle("Error")
                                .setMessage("The Square Side length is empty")               
                                .setPositiveButton("OK", null).show();          
                            } else {
                                double result = new Double(m1_sqs1.getText().toString()) * new Double(m1_sqs1.getText().toString());   
                                m1_sa_in.setText(Double.toString(result));
                                    } 
                        if (((m1ssspinner.getSelectedItem() == "Rectangle"))) {
                            if ((m1_rs1.getText().length() == 0)           
                            || (m1_rs1.getText().toString() == " ")
                            || (m1_rs1.getText().toString() == " ")
                            || (m1_rs1.getText().length() == 0)){
                                show = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext).setTitle("Error")
                                .setMessage("A Rectangle Side length is empty")               
                                .setPositiveButton("OK", null).show();
                            } else {
                                double result = new Double(m1_rs1.getText().toString()) * new Double(m1_rs2.getText().toString());   
                                m1_sa_in.setText(Double.toString(result));
                                    } 
                        if (((m1ssspinner.getSelectedItem() == "Circle"))) {
                            if ((m1_cd.getText().length() == 0)           
                            || (m1_cd.getText().toString() == " ") 
                            || (m1_cd.getText().toString() == " ")){
                                show = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext).setTitle("Error")
                                .setMessage("The Circle Diameter is empty")               
                                .setPositiveButton("OK", null).show();
                            } else {
                                double result = new Double(m1_cd.getText().toString()) * new Double(m1_cd.getText().toString());   
                                m1_sa_in.setText(Double.toString(result));
                                    } 
                        if (((m1ssspinner.getSelectedItem() == "Elliptical"))) {
                            if ((m1_els1.getText().length() == 0)           
                            || (m1_els1.getText().toString() == " ")
                            || (m1_els2.getText().toString() == 0)
                            || (m1_els2.getText().toString() == " ")){
                                show = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext).setTitle("Error")
                                .setMessage("An Elliptical Diameter is empty")               
                                .setPositiveButton("OK", null).show();
                            } else {
                                double result = new Double(m1_els1.getText().toString()) * new Double(m1_els2.getText().toString());   
                                m1_sa_in.setText(Double.toString(result));
                            }
        );

//
// End OnClick Event in each button.
//

// 
// check media availability
//

boolean mExternalStorageAvailable = false;
boolean mExternalStorageWriteable = false;
String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) { 

// We can read and write the media    

mExternalStorageAvailable = mExternalStorageWriteable = true;
} else if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(state)) {    

// We can only read the media    

mExternalStorageAvailable = true;    
mExternalStorageWriteable = false;} else {    

// Something else is wrong. It may be one of many other states, but all we need    
//  to know is we can neither read nor write    

mExternalStorageAvailable = mExternalStorageWriteable = false;       
}    

// 
// end check media availability
//           

// 
// create METHOD 1 STACK SHAPE SPINNER  (m1_ss_spinner) with displayed text 'centered'
// 

Spinner m1ssspinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.m1_ss_spinner);        
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> m1ssadapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.m1_ss_list, R.layout.my_normal_spinner_style);            
    m1ssadapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    m1ssspinner.setAdapter(m1ssadapter); 

// 
// get METHOD 1 STACK SHAPE UNIT  (m1_ss_unit)
// 

    Object m1_ss_unit = (m1ssspinner.getSelectedItem());

// 
// create METHOD 1 SQUARE_SIDE1 SPINNER  (m1_sqs1_spinner) with displayed text 'centered'
// 

    Spinner m1sqs1spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.m1_sqs1_spinner);        
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> m1sqs1adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.m1_sqs1_list, R.layout.my_normal_spinner_style);            
        m1sqs1adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);            
        m1sqs1spinner.setAdapter(m1sqs1adapter); 

// 
// create METHOD 1 RECTANGLE_SIDE1 SPINNER  (m1_rs1_spinner) with displayed text 'centered'
// 

    Spinner m1rs1spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.m1_rs1_spinner);        
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> m1rs1adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.m1_rs1_list, R.layout.my_normal_spinner_style);            
        m1rs1adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);            
        m1rs1spinner.setAdapter(m1rs1adapter);

// 
// create METHOD 1 RECTANGLE_SIDE2 SPINNER  (m1_rs2_spinner) with displayed text 'centered'
// 

    Spinner m1rs2spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.m1_rs2_spinner);        
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> m1rs2adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.m1_rs2_list, R.layout.my_normal_spinner_style);            
        m1rs2adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);            
        m1rs2spinner.setAdapter(m1rs2adapter);      

// 
// create METHOD 1 CIRCULAR DIAMETER SPINNER  (m1_cd_spinner) with displayed text 'centered'
// 

    Spinner m1cdspinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.m1_cd_spinner);        
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> m1cdadapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.m1_cd_list, R.layout.my_normal_spinner_style);            
        m1cdadapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);            
        m1cdspinner.setAdapter(m1cdadapter);

// 
// create METHOD 1 ELLIPTICAL DIAMETER1 SPINNER  (m1_cd_spinner) with displayed text 'centered'
// 

    Spinner m1els1spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.m1_els1_spinner);        
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> m1els1adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.m1_els1_list, R.layout.my_normal_spinner_style);            
        m1els1adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);            
        m1els1spinner.setAdapter(m1els1adapter);

// 
// create METHOD 1 ELLIPTICAL DIAMETER2 SPINNER  (m1_cd_spinner) with displayed text 'centered'
// 

    Spinner m1els2spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.m1_els2_spinner);        
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> m1els2adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.m1_els2_list, R.layout.my_normal_spinner_style);            
        m1els2adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);            
        m1els2spinner.setAdapter(m1cdadapter);          

}
```

Comment: I suggest you pare down the code snippets included in the question to the sections which are giving you the errors ... that's too much code for me to go through :-) as an aside, if you're having trouble matching parens and semicolons, I would also suggest that you refactor the methods to simplify each moving part. For example, move the simple control init code (findbyview, etc.) into a separate private method. Implement the click listeners as class members rather than inline ... separating all of these things will help you understand where the error lies

Comment: what is the exact error in logcat?

Comment: There're number of issues: Formatting (also helps to track brackets), mContext variable (seems it's just useless).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following have no closing bracket ...

```
btnExecute.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { ... 
    public void onClick(View arg0) { ...
        if (((m1ssspinner.getSelectedItem() == "Square"))) { ...
            if (((m1ssspinner.getSelectedItem() == "Rectangle"))) { ...            
            if (((m1ssspinner.getSelectedItem() == "Circle"))) { ...
            if (((m1ssspinner.getSelectedItem() == "Elliptical"))) { ...
```

Your btnExecute.setOnClickListener should look like this

```
btnExecute.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
            ... your if statements ... 
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

There are so many problems here I don't even know where to begin.  This wont compile of course because you have unbalanced {}, but thats not the least of your problems

Your very first if/then includes all the others and precludes any of the others from ever resolving to true for instance

```
if (((m1ssspinner.getSelectedItem() == "Square")))
```

Encapsulates all the other tests such as the next one which is

```
if (((m1ssspinner.getSelectedItem() == "Rectangle")))
```

If the first is true, the second will never be.

You also have local and class scoped variables of different types with the same name and the local is not initialized (or of the right type)

```
AdapterView<SpinnerAdapter> m1ssspinner; // Probably not what you want to use ... 

Spinner m1ssspinner = (Spinner) ...
```

Then you have blocks with duplicate tests

```
if ((m1_rs1.getText().length() == 0)           // Same test twice! 
    || (m1_rs1.getText().toString() == " ")
    || (m1_rs1.getText().toString() == " ")
    || (m1_rs1.getText().length() == 0))
```

Or this one where you are doing same, but also testing a string against an int

```
 if (((m1ssspinner.getSelectedItem() == "Elliptical"))) {
    if ((m1_els1.getText().length() == 0)           
    || (m1_els1.getText().toString() == " ")
    || (m1_els2.getText().toString() == 0)       // you probably meant int!
    || (m1_els2.getText().toString() == " ")){
```

Also your tests are comparing objects returned from the spinner with string literals (they wont match)

You are intializing your view classes at the top level of the class vs. in the oncreate after setcontent view etc. etc. etc.

Anyway this block at least will compile, but this program simply wont work as written, you still have a heck of lot things to work out.

My advice is to take this one step at a time, if you are finding that you have rats nest of if/then you probably need to rethink the solution

```
btnExecute.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
{
     private AlertDialog show;
     public void onClick(View arg0) 
     {
         //AdapterView<SpinnerAdapter> m1ssspinner; // Probably you meant to use the                  class scoped of same name  

         if (((m1ssspinner.getSelectedItem() == "Square"))) {
             if ((m1_sqs1.getText().length() == 0)           
                 || (m1_sqs1.getText().toString() == " ")) {           
                     show = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext).setTitle("Error")
                        .setMessage("The Square Side length is empty")               
                        .setPositiveButton("OK", null).show();          
                    } else 
                    {
                        double result = new Double(m1_sqs1.getText().toString()) * new                             Double(m1_sqs1.getText().toString());   
                        m1_sa_in.setText(Double.toString(result));
                    } 
     } else      

     if (((m1ssspinner.getSelectedItem() == "Rectangle"))) {
            if ((m1_rs1.getText().length() == 0)           
            || (m1_rs1.getText().toString() == " ")
            || (m1_rs1.getText().toString() == " ")
            || (m1_rs1.getText().length() == 0))           {
            show = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext).setTitle("Error")
            .setMessage("A Rectangle Side length is empty")               
            .setPositiveButton("OK", null).show();
            } else 
            {
                 double result = new Double(m1_rs1.getText().toString()) * new                           Double(m1_rs2.getText().toString());   
            m1_sa_in.setText(Double.toString(result));
            } 
     } else       

     if (((m1ssspinner.getSelectedItem() == "Circle"))) {
            if ((m1_cd.getText().length() == 0)           
                 || (m1_cd.getText().toString() == " ") 
                 || (m1_cd.getText().toString() == " "))
            {
                show = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext).setTitle("Error")
                    .setMessage("The Circle Diameter is empty")               
                    .setPositiveButton("OK", null).show();
            } else 
            {
                 double result = new Double(m1_cd.getText().toString()) * new Double(m1_cd.getText().toString());   
                         m1_sa_in.setText(Double.toString(result));
            }
      } else
      if ((m1ssspinner.getSelectedItem() == "Elliptical")) {
                    if ((m1_els1.getText().length() == 0)           
                    || (m1_els1.getText().toString() == " ")
                    || (m1_els2.getText().length() == 0)
                    || (m1_els2.getText().toString() == " "))
                    {
                        show = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext).setTitle("Error")
                        .setMessage("An Elliptical Diameter is empty")               
                        .setPositiveButton("OK", null).show();
                    } else {
                        double result = new Double(m1_els1.getText().toString()) * new Double(m1_els2.getText().toString());   
                        m1_sa_in.setText(Double.toString(result));
                    }
                }

            }   
        }

        );
```

Comment: wow -thanks for the input.  I started this apk with just an idea that I finally got layouts working then I proceeded to the java code, whcih I have no experience which is very evident.  Last night I was feeling good that I was able to the square side 1 input to produce the correct answer.  Today I decided I would evaluate the 'shape' spinner and then select the proper inputs to do the math.  I thought I was good.  I also laugh and feel like a caveman trying to create a space ship.  While this is close to the end of a layout I am going to struggle a little longer before giving up.

Comment: i have the code compiling but fcing when running.  I am going to try and figure out why.  Could I email you the code to look at since comments are limited.  I am so close to being done that I cant quit.  I have been in a learning mode for 3 weeks and have no java experience.  This started out being fun but the java stuff is taking it toll.

Comment: @WmBurkert, well I can look quickly at it, but I can't really debug your code, day job and all!

Answer (score 0):

Below seems wrong. put AlertDialog show inside the function

```
btnExecute.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
{             

private AlertDialog show;
public void onClick(View arg0)
```

Answer (score 0):

For errors with brackets. I suggest you go through and set a comment with a number.

Add 1 if you open a bracket, and subtract 1 if you have a close bracket.

This will help you overcome the problem in the future:

```
if(true)
{ //1
    while(true)
    { //2
    } //1

} //0
```

Answer (score 0):

problem is in your btnExecute.you didn't put a '}'.See after last else in btnExecute's  you have to put another }